# Performance improvement for increasing and decreasing brightness and contrast of canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas

I am trying to increase and decrease brightness and contrast of canvas using input range. For that I used following code.

Html:

```
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <input id="range" type="range" value="0" min="-100" max="100">
```

Javascript:

```
brightnessRange = document.getElementById('range');
brightnessRange?.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'http://webgl-workshop.com/assets/e826db271aa3c03c69c4aca1e20abf5b.jpg';

    imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    let arr = imgData.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 4) {
        arr[i] = arr1[i] + 255 * (+brightnessRange.value / 100);
        arr[i + 1] = arr1[i + 1] + 255 * (+brightnessRange.value / 100);
        arr[i + 2] = arr1[i + 2] + 255 * (+brightnessRange.value / 100);
    }

    imgData.data = arr;
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}
```

I am using similar type of code for contrast. Above code is working too slowly. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Please note: I don't want to use context filters as it does not support in some browsers.

Comment: Load your image only once, if you are going to do a lot of manipulation over the original ImageData, work on copies of that ImageData and keep the original in memory, don't try to retrieve it from the context every time. And depriving everyone from using the right tools because a few can't is a bad idea. Make it right where it can be, and only add less performant polyfills for Safari.

Answer (score 0):

For brightness, you can use `globalCompositeOperation` as described here: [HTML5 Canvas brightness control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118229/html5-canvas-brightness-control)

As for contrast, without filters, the only way you can improve performance is to use WebGL with the canvas.