# html5 canvas apply filter along path

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have an image, and an object inside of the image.  I would like to increase the brightness of just the part of the image that is related to the object.  I can find the object in terms of a `path`, or probably some other canvas thing.  Is it possible to apply a [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) to only part of an image?

I have naively tried the following, based on [a full-image brightness control solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118229/html5-canvas-brightness-control):

```js
const imageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss_1840_by_Jensen.jpg/800px-Carl_Friedrich_Gauss_1840_by_Jensen.jpg";
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillText("Please wait loading image..",20,20);
const image = new Image;
image.src = imageUrl;
image.onload = () => {
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;     
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  slider.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
    if (slider.value !== slideOldVal) {
      setBrightness(Number(slider.value));
    }
    val.textContent = slider.value;
    slideOldVal = Number(slider.value);
  });
}

function setBrightness(value) {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    ctx.filter = `brightness(${value + 100}%)`;
    ctx.strokeStyle = `rgb(255,255,255,0)`;
    ctx.lineWidth = 16;
 
    let path2 = new Path2D();
    path2.moveTo(220, 60);
    path2.arc(170, 60, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke(path2);
    
    ctx.filter = `brightness(${100}%)`;
}

var slideOldVal;
```

```html
Brightness<input id="slider" type="range" min="-100" max="400" value="0" step="1"></input><span id="val"></span><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

This is an attempt to increase the brightness along a circular path situated in the top left corner of the image.  This code actually accomplishes nothing.

Is there a way to increase the brightness of only part of an image using an HTML5 canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter will only apply on the next painting, but here the next painting will be all transparent, given your `strokeStyle`. What you want is to draw the image again with that filter, but only where the arc's stroke will be.
For this you have various solutions.

One of these is to use [compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation), this will allow you to use your stroke as a mask, and apply the filter only on it. Even then you'd have various ways of building this, some depending on if your original image has transparency, some using offscreen canvas etc. Here is one among all these.

```js
const imageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss_1840_by_Jensen.jpg/800px-Carl_Friedrich_Gauss_1840_by_Jensen.jpg";
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const path2 = new Path2D();
// I moved a bit the arc so that the filter is better visible
path2.moveTo(320, 160);
path2.arc(270, 160, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

ctx.fillText("Please wait loading image..",20,20);
const image = new Image;
image.src = imageUrl;
image.onload = () => {
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  ctx.lineWidth = 16;
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  slider.addEventListener("input", () => {
    setBrightness(Number(slider.value));
    val.textContent = slider.value;
  });
}

function setBrightness(value) {
  // start with only the arc stroke on the context
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke(path2);
  // use it as a mask so that the image is only visible where the stroke is
  // with the expected filter applied
  ctx.filter = `brightness(${value + 100}%)`;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";    
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  // draw the image again, only where we didn't draw yet,
  // without filter
  ctx.filter = "none";
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

  // reset gCO
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}
```

```html
Brightness<input id="slider" type="range" min="-100" max="400" value="0" step=".1"><span id="val"></span><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Another solution since all you do is to `drawImage()` a resource, is to create a [`CanvasPattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern) from that resource and use that as the `strokeStyle`, less code, but might not suite all use cases.

```js
const imageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss_1840_by_Jensen.jpg/800px-Carl_Friedrich_Gauss_1840_by_Jensen.jpg";
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const path2 = new Path2D();
path2.moveTo(320, 160);
path2.arc(270, 160, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

ctx.fillText("Please wait loading image..",20,20);
const image = new Image;
image.src = imageUrl;
image.onload = () => {
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  // since we don't change the strokeStyle we can store it directly here
  // if you need to change the strokeStyle during your app's life
  // store it in its own variable and set it as strokeStyle every time.
  ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.createPattern(image, "no-repeat");
  ctx.lineWidth = 16;
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  slider.addEventListener("input", () => {
    setBrightness(Number(slider.value));
    val.textContent = slider.value;
  });
}

function setBrightness(value) {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  ctx.filter = `brightness(${value + 100}%)`;
  ctx.stroke(path2);
  ctx.filter = "none";
}
```

```html
Brightness<input id="slider" type="range" min="-100" max="400" value="0" step="0.1"><span id="val"></span><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Finally, since you only do use the brightness filter, you could use blending modes to get a **similar** effect, not exactly the same as the CSS filter, but which would have the benefit of working in Safari browsers.

```js
const imageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss_1840_by_Jensen.jpg/800px-Carl_Friedrich_Gauss_1840_by_Jensen.jpg";
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const path2 = new Path2D();
path2.moveTo(320, 160);
path2.arc(270, 160, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

ctx.fillText("Please wait loading image..",20,20);
const image = new Image;
image.src = imageUrl;
image.onload = () => {
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  ctx.lineWidth = 16;
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  slider.addEventListener("input", () => {
    setBrightness(Number(slider.value));
    val.textContent = slider.value;
  });
}

function setBrightness(value) {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  // kind of hackish multipass "overlay" blending to approach brightness()
  // I'm sure there are better ways to do this
  ctx.strokeStyle = value < 0 ? "black" : "white";
  const numberOfPass = Math.abs(value) / 200;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "overlay";
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPass - 1; i++) {
    ctx.stroke(path2);
  }
  const lastPassAlpha = numberOfPass - Math.round(numberOfPass);
  ctx.globalAlpha = lastPassAlpha || 1;
  ctx.stroke(path2);
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}
```

```html
Brightness<input id="slider" type="range" min="-100" max="400" value="0" step="0.1"></input><span id="val"></span><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```